# Is there a silver bullet to importing XML data into SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I've tried the Import/Export wizard, but there is no XML driver under the Data source drop down. Is there a way to import XML data into SQL Express without writing an app to do it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175160.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

See the article I wrote about [importing XML into the database using T/SQL](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1347994_mem1,00.html).

Comment: I'mg getting a 404 page not found

Comment: Strange, the link is working for me.  Let me know if it still isn't working and I'll see what I can find out.